Generating a specific matrix in PyTorch by cumulative products without for loops
In pytorch, I would like to generate a specific NxN matrix starting from a (N-1)-element array, following a specific order of cumulative products along the elements of the array to populate each row and column of the matrix.
Starting from the array: array
This should be the output matrix: matrix
I would like to do this without python for loops, in order to avoid significant slowdowns in the forward() function of my model
Here is a working example of this, using a for loop:
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gen_matrix(array):
    N = array.shape[0] + 1
    m = torch.ones(N,N)
    for i in range(N):
        m[i   ,i+1:] = torch.cumprod(array[i:],0)
        m[i+1:,i   ] = torch.cumprod(array[i:],0)
    return m

example_array = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.3, 0.2])
output_matrix = gen_matrix(example_array)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(output_matrix)
plt.colorbar()

Is it possible to substitute the loop with some pytorch method?
I tried to look for a suitable method, however I'm still new to pytorch and couldn't find a way to achieve this without slicing and looping on every row. The output matrix is symmetric as it is equal to its transpose, so I can generate half of it using a combination of .T and .tril(), but I still end up looping over either rows or columns.

Very interesting, took me a while to figure out a solution! A possible improvement would be to vectorize the cumulative product.
Start by concatenating a 1 at the front and expand row-wise, this will be the output tensor:
>>> m = torch.cat([torch.ones(1),array])[None].repeat(N,1)
tensor([[1.0000, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000]])

To apply torch.cumprod along dim=1, we need to set the lower triangle to 1:
>>> m = m.triu(1) + torch.ones_like(m).tril(0)
tensor([[1.0000, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 1.0000, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0500, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 0.3000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 0.2000],
        [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000]])

To get the desired results copy the upper triangle, transpose it, and add to  m.
All in all, it comes down to:
def gen_matrix(array):
    N = len(array) + 1
    m = torch.cat([torch.ones(1),array])[None].repeat(N,1)
    m = m.triu(1) + torch.ones_like(m).tril(0)
    m = m.cumprod(1)
    return m.triu() + m.triu(1).T


Thanks, this works great! One question, what is the [None] needed for in line 3?

This is used to prepend a singleton dimension to the array before repeating it N times. It is equivalent to unsqueeze(0). You can read more about it here.
